# Ethereum raw data files folder

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, database

Where is the folder on Mac OSX where Ethereum put raw blockchain data? I find only *.ldb files, but as I understand it is only the index of full database.

For example, in Bitcoin there is blk*.dat files. Is there something like this in Ethereum? And if yes, where this stored?

Comment: Why would .ldb files be only an index? ldb stands for LevelDB, which is the database formath that geth uses

Comment: @TjadenHess LevelDB is the Index_Value database only.